# Remote Execution of Powershell Command with PowerShell-Core Version

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

I am trying to execute Powershell command remotely, my problem is that the Powershell is used is version 4.0, and I want to execute my command remotely using Powershell Core 6.0.4.

I tried to use this command on the remote host

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -name microsoft.powershell -psversion 6.0 -FORCE
```

And getting this error:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration : Cannot bind parameter 'PSVersion' to the target. Exception setting "PSVersion": "The
value 6.0 is not valid for the PSVersion parameter. The available values are 2.0,3.0 and 4.0."
```

I got version 6.0.4 installed on my remote machine.

I know it uses version 4 to execute my remote command, because

```
 Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion};
```

returns:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision PSComputerName
-----  -----  -----  -------- --------------
4      0      -1     -1       IIS-DEV2
```

Any ideas how to force it to use version 6?

Comment: `Install-PowerShellRemoting.ps1` should be part of PowerShell Core installation.

Comment: @PetSerAl Didn't understand your answer. I installed powershell core like any other program, what is this script your are talking about, be more specific

Comment: And like any other program installation it adds some files in your system. Someone among them should be named `Install-PowerShellRemoting.ps1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As shown in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984600/45375), *obsolete* PowerShell Core versions indeed require running **`Install-PowerShellRemoting.ps1`** in order to enable a given computer to act as remoting endpoint (i.e., to allow other computers to target it with remoting cmdlets such as `New-PSSession` or `Invoke-Command`), said script was a ***stopgap* that is no longer needed** in current PowerShell Core versions.

  - From [WS-Management (WSMan) Remoting in PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/wsman-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6), as of this writing:

> The installation script is a short-term solution until we add additional functionality to Enable-PSRemoting to perform the same action.

- ***Current* versions of PowerShell Core and all versions going forward should use the [`Enable-PSRemoting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting)** cmdlet, as in Windows PowerShell.

<sup>**Note**: As of this writing, [WS-Management (WSMan) Remoting in PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/wsman-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6) doesn't yet mention that the current 6.x version no longer needs the stopgap script - [see this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5597). Also note that `Enable-PSRemoting` is **not available on *Unix-like* platforms as of v7.0** (and neither is the obsolete `Install-PowerShellRemoting.ps1` script).</sup>

---

As an aside re **targeting a *specific* PowerShell Core version**:

While `-ConfigurationName Powershell.6.0.4` does work if you want to target a very *specific version*, **`Enable-PSRemoting` also creates a `PowerShell.<OwnMajorVersionOnly>` configuration that doesn't require your to specify the full version number** (which is likely to change, as you update PowerShell Core on the endpoint machine).

Therefore, consider using the following instead, using the example of having run `Enable-PSRemoting` from a PowerShell 7.x version on the remoting endpoint:

```
-ConfigurationName PowerShell.7
```

For more information, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58238481/45375).

Answer (score 0):

In the installation folder of powershell core, there is a script file `Install-PowerShellRemoting`,

Run the script in the remote server you want the session to,
and than when remoting use the following:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName IIS-DEV2 -port 5985 -Credential $mycreds -ConfigurationName "powershell.6.0.4"
```

It worked, and got me a session with Powershell core.