# PowerShell remoting: Controlling what edition is being targeted (PowerShell Core or Windows PowerShell); the state of cross-platform remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm, powershell-core, wsman

This self-answered question, which focuses on Windows<sup>[1]</sup>, addresses the following aspects:

Now that there are ***two* PowerShell editions** - the legacy, **Windows-only *Windows PowerShell*** and the **cross-platform PowerShell *Core***, both may be installed on a given Windows machine:

- **How can I tell which PowerShell edition will execute [*remote* commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq)**, such as via `Invoke-Command -ComputerName`?
- **How can I target a specific edition**, both *ad hoc* and *persistently*, through configuration?

Note:

**For an edition to be targetable via remoting on a given machine, it must be [set up for remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements):**

- Only *Windows PowerShell* is *automatically* set up for remoting, but only on *servers* running Windows Server 2012 or higher.
- As of v7, PowerShell *Core* doesn't come with Windows yet; if you're using the official installer, you're given the option of enabling remoting during the installation.

In any event, you can **use [`Enable-PSRemoting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-6) to (re-)enable PowerShell remoting on demand**, which:

- must be run *from the respective edition*.
- must be run *with administrative privileges*

---

[1] That is, the question focuses on [WinRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Management)-based remoting (WinRM is a Windows-specific implementation of the DTMF [WSMan (WS-Management) standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Management)).

As for ***cross-platform* remoting with PowerShell Core**:

- You can already use **[SSH-based remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core)**, on all platforms:

  - Using SSH-based remoting involves mostly the same cmdlets as WinRM-based remoting, though the parameters involved differ; most notably, you specify the target computer(s) via the `-HostName` parameter rather than 
    the `-ComputerName` parameter.
  - **Limitations (as of v7)**: "SSH-based remoting doesn't currently support remote endpoint configuration and Just Enough Administration (JEA)."
- For ***Unix-to-Windows* remoting** (*Unix* referring to Unix-like platforms such as macOS and Linux) - that is, remoting into a Windows machine from a Unix-like machine - you can alternatively use WinRM-based remoting with additional configuration:

  - On the Windows machine:

    - SSL connections must be enabled by configuring WinRM for HTTPS.
    - The user accounts to be used from the Unix-like machines must be defined as *local* user accounts in the *local* Administrators group - domain accounts won't work.
  - The Unix-like machines must use the remoting cmdlets with the `-Authentication Basic -UseSsl` parameters.
  - See [about_Remote_Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements#basic-authentication-limitations-on-linux-and-macos)
- **A Unix WSMan-based implementation is being worked on in the [psl-omi-provider repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/psl-omi-provider)**, which already enables *Linux* machines to act as remoting targets (that is, the *server* component is already usable - it's not clear to me whether it can also be installed on *macOS*); the client component, however, is not yet production-ready as of this writing.
  Once the client client component is available, uniform WSMan-based cross-platform remoting will be possible, both between Unix-like machines (Linux, macOS) and between Unix-like machines and Windows machines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note**: Changing what remote endpoint PowerShell [Core] targets *by default* - which as of 7.0 is still *Window PowerShell* - is being considered: see [GitHub issue #11616](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11616).

---

**It is the locally specified *remoting session configuration* that  determines what PowerShell edition, and possibly version, will be used on the *remote* machine**:

- *Ad hoc*, you can use the **`-ConfigurationName` parameter** of remoting cmdlets such as `Invoke-Command`, `New-PSSession`, and `Enter-PSSession` to specify a session configuration explicitly.
- *Persistently*, via configuration, you can **set the *default* session configuration** via the [**`$PSSessionConfigurationName`** preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#pssessionconfigurationname) (the linked help topic also dicusses other remote-session-related preference variables, namely `$PSSessionApplicationName` and `$PSSessionOption`)

  - By default, clients connect to session configuration `microsoft.powershell` on the remote machine (see below). Therefore, **you can alternatively *change the definition of* this configuration *on the remote target machine*, but note that this means that *all* clients that use the defaults will use the redefined configuration** - see bottom for how to achieve this redefinition.

**On the *target machine* of a remoting operation**, **`Get-PSSessionConfiguration`** cmdlet lists all registered session configurations that clients can use to connect to, and which you can manage with `Register-PSSessionConfiguration` and `Unregister-PSSessionConfiguration`:

- **Caveat**: `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` must be run in an *elevated* session (as administrator), and, due to a *bug* in Windows PowerShell 5.1, you may have to run the following dummy command first: `$null = Get-Command Test-WSMan`, so as to ensure that the `wsman:` drive is defined).
- Session configurations whose names are prefixed with **`'microsoft.powershell`'** belong to ***Windows PowerShell***.
- Prefix **`'PowerShell.'`** refers to PowerShell ***Core***.

`$PSSessionConfigurationName` defaults to `'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell'` in *both* editions, which means that ***Windows PowerShell* is by default targeted on remote machines *even if you're running from PowerShell Core***:

- The `Microsoft.PowerShell` part refers to the (64-bit) Windows PowerShell session configuration, as listed by `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` (in lowercase).
- The `http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/` prefix is *optional* and can be omitted; note that using `https:` in the prefix does *not* work and will *not* automatically switch to an SSL-based transport; for the latter, [explicit configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements#basic-authentication-limitations-on-linux-and-macos) is needed. Note  that HTTPS/SSL-based remoting isn't necessary if all of your remoting happens within a Windows domain.

**To target PowerShell *Core* (PowerShell v6+) on a remote machine**:

- Generally, PowerShell *Core* session configurations are *version-specific*, and you have two choices:

  - **Target a *major* PowerShell Core version** - e.g., `PowerShell.7` - using whatever the latest v7.x version is installed on the target machine.

    - **This is preferable**, because your code then doesn't require updating every time you install a patch or minor version update on the target machine.
  - Target a *specific* version - e.g., `PowerShell.7.1.2`

    - Do this only if you have multiple, side-by-side installations that share the same major version, and you explicitly need to target one of them.
  - Again, running `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` on the target machine, from an *elevated* session, tells you the names of all registered session configurations.
- **To target PowerShell Core *ad hoc***, use `-ConfigurationName PowerShell.7`, for instance:

```bash
# Connect to computer $comp and make it execute $PSVersionTable 
# in PowerShell Core v7.x, which tells you what PowerShell edition 
# and version is running.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ConfigurationName PowerShell.7 { $PSVersionTable }
```

- **To target PowerShell Core *by default, persistently*, from a given *client* machine**, add something like the following to your `$PROFILE` file:

```bash
# When remoting, default to running PowerShell Core v7.x on the
# the target machines:
$PSSessionConfigurationName = 'PowerShell.7'
```

- **To have *all clients* of a given remote *server* machine target PowerShell Core *by default, persistently***, you must **redefine the server's `microsoft.powershell` session configuration**, which requires administrative privileges; you can adapt the following snippet:

```bash
# Run WITH ELEVATION (as administrator) and
# ONLY IF YOU UNDERSTAND THE IMPLICATIONS.

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# The configuration whose definition you want to make the new default.
$newDefaultConfigSource = 'PowerShell.7'

# Standard registry locations and names.
$defaultConfigName = 'Microsoft.PowerShell'
$configXmlValueName = 'ConfigXml'
$configRootKey = 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Plugin'

# Rename the current default configuration XML to "ConfigXml.OLD" to keep a backup.
Rename-ItemProperty $configRootKey\$defaultConfigName $configXmlValueName -NewName "$configXmlValueName.OLD"

# Get the configuration XML from the configuration that should become the new default.
# Modify it to replace the source configuration name with the default configuration name.
$xmlText = (Get-ItemPropertyValue $configRootKey\$newDefaultConfigSource $configXmlValueName) -replace 
             ('\b{0}\b' -f [regex]::Escape($newDefaultConfigSource)), $defaultConfigName

# Save the modified XML as the default configuration's config XML.
Set-ItemProperty $configRootKey\$defaultConfigName $configXmlValueName $xmlText

# Restart the WinRM service for changes to take effect.
Restart-Service WinRM
```