# Update powershell to the latest revision

Tags: powershell

I have two different revision of PowerShell in different machines. The local one have the following one:

| Major | Minor | Build | Revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 17763 | 1007 |

And the virtual machine has the following one:

| Major | Minor | Build | Revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 17763 | 771 |

As you can see that it has the same: Major, Minor, and Build values except the Revision values. I am not sure if it is behind the failure of the command:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name $RepoKeyName -SourceLocation $RepoKeyValue
    -PublishLocation $RepoKeyValue -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Verbose
```

The above snippet works fine on the local machine but not on the virtual machine and it fails in the virtual machine with the following error:

`parameter 'SourceLocation' is an invalid Web Uri. Please ensure that it meets the Web Uri requirements.`

And this is why I want to update the PowerShell in the virtual machine to the latest revision value. How to do it?

Answer (score 53):

If you have Microsoft's [winget](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli) app (Windows package manager), you can run the following command to update to the most recent version of PowerShell:

```bash
winget install Microsoft.PowerShell
```

Comment: That's good to know, but to be clear: This applies only to [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the install-on-demand cross-platform PowerShell edition, not the comes-with-the-OS Windows-only _Windows PowerShell_ edition, which cannot be updated _on demand_ (only indirectly, via Windows Update).

Comment: To update to PowerShell 7.2.0 from 7.1.5, I had to use `winget upgrade PowerShell`

Comment: I had to explicitly state `winget upgrade Microsoft.PowerShell` to get 7.2.1 from 7.2.0.

Answer (score 30):

###### If you're running Windows 11 or have updated App Installer in Windows 10.

Update PowerShell using Windows Package Manager (winget)

```
winget upgrade Microsoft.PowerShell
```

You also can install PowerShell by using below command via winget

```
winget install Microsoft.PowerShell
```

Learn more:

- [winget in Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/)
- [winget in GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli)

Comment: I had to use `winget install Microsoft.PowerShell` to upgrade from 7.2.5 to 7.2.6; `winget upgrade` reported "No applicable upgrade available."

Comment: To be clear: This applies only to [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the install-on-demand cross-platform PowerShell edition, not the comes-with-the-OS Windows-only _Windows PowerShell_ edition that the question is about. _Windows PowerShell_ can NOT be updated on demand (only indirectly, via Windows Update). Switching _editions_, from Windows PowerShell to PowerShell (Core) is more than just a fully backward-compatible update, and requires careful planning.

Answer (score 11):

**You can never update *Windows PowerShell* installations *on demand*** - **except, in the past, if you upgraded to a new *major* version, but v5.1 is the *last* version that will ever be released**, given that Windows PowerShell is in maintenance-only will see no new development, **unlike its successor, the cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) edition.<sup>[1]</sup>**

Note:

- **While *switching* to the *PowerShell (Core)* edition<sup>[1]</sup> - where all future development effort will go - is advisable in general, doing so is not something to be done *casually* and requires a *deliberate decision***:

  - *PowerShell (Core)* is *mostly*, but *not fully backward-compatible* with *Windows PowerShell*, and certain cmdlets are unavailable, except via a [compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility) that has its limitations both in terms of performance and type fidelity.
  - *PowerShell (Core)* is installed *alongside* Windows PowerShell and has *different CLI* (`pwsh.exe` rather than `powershell.exe`) and *different SDKs* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375)); also, targeting *PowerShell (Core)* via PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) requires explicit configuration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238482/45375).

---

##### *Windows PowerShell*-specific considerations:

***Revisions* of v5.1 are delivered as part of *Windows updates***.

However, **you can selectively update the [`PowerShellGet` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet), in which the problem-causing `Register-PSRepository` command is defined**:

While you normally would just run `Update-Module PowerShellGet`, a different approach is required the first time, when switching from the *bundled* `PowerShellGet` module to the latest version from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/):

- Open an *elevated* session (Run as Administrator).
- Execute the following (add `-Verbose` to get detailed information):

  ```
    Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force
  ```

<sup>The `-Force` is to enable installation even though a module by that name is already installed; you may still see a prompt about downloading the NuGet package provider.

Note that the old `PowerShellGet` version will linger in a different location, but the new one will take precedence over it.</sup>

After this initial switch to the gallery-installed version, you'll be able to use
`Update-Module PowerShellGet` for future versions.

---

You can use the [`Get-Command`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet to discover a given command's module of origin; e.g.:

```
PS> (Get-Command Register-PSRepository).Module

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     2.1.4                 PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapability…}
```

---

[1] **PowerShell (Core) 7+ versions *can* be updated on demand** - however, as of v7.2.x, PowerShell (Core) **doesn't come with Windows** and **initially requires manual installation**. However, you can now install and update it via the **Microsoft Store** application or, ***programmatically*, using `winget.exe`** (which comes with the `App Installer` Microsoft Store application, which recent versions of Windows *ship with*):

- **Initial installation:**

  ```
  winget install Microsoft.PowerShell
  ```
- **Later upgrade:**

  ```
  winget upgrade Microsoft.PowerShell
  ```

Note: Use `Microsoft.PowerShell.Preview` to install / upgrade the latest *preview* version instead.

Comment: I haven't tried this approach, not yet. But this seems the best answer so far, `winget install Microsoft.PowerShell` (as per other answers) says successful installation but `$PSVersionTable` doesn't get any further than `5.1.19041.revision`

Comment: @rellampec, I've updated the footnote with more details on the `winget.exe` approach, but note that it only applies to the cross-platform, install-on-demand [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition. The question - and the focus of this answer - is the legacy, ships-with-Windows, in-maintenance-only-mode _Windows PowerShell_ edition, whose latest and _last-ever_ version is v5.1.x

Answer (score 9):

Run the following command from command prompt wait till gets downloaded, and it will prompt to installation wizard follow the instructions to install it.

```
Invoke-Expression "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI"
```

Comment: I was curious what iex stood for (Invoke-Expression). Now I know.

Comment: To be clear: This applies only to [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the install-on-demand cross-platform PowerShell edition, not the comes-with-the-OS Windows-only _Windows PowerShell_ edition that the question is about. _Windows PowerShell_ can NOT be updated on demand (only indirectly, via Windows Update). Switching _editions_, from Windows PowerShell to PowerShell (Core) is more than just a fully backward-compatible update, and requires careful planning.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1:**
Go to this link:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/

Find Assets and click on **Assets** word.

Download and install **.msi** link.

---

**Solution2:**

Go to this link for download Windows Package Manager:

https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases

Find Assets and click on **Assets** word.

Download : **Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle**

Execute the downloaded file and click on update.

Open your command prompt or powershell and execute this command on it:

**winget install Microsoft.PowerShell**

If you have Mircrosoft.PowerShell execute this command:

**winget upgrade Microsoft.PowerShell**

---

For figure out your powershell version: execute **host** command in your powershell.
[image]

Comment: To be clear: This applies only to [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the install-on-demand cross-platform PowerShell edition, not the comes-with-the-OS Windows-only _Windows PowerShell_ edition that the question is about. _Windows PowerShell_ can NOT be updated on demand (only indirectly, via Windows Update). Switching _editions_, from Windows PowerShell to PowerShell (Core) is more than just a fully backward-compatible update, and requires careful planning.