# how to get winrm to use powershell 7 for remote sessions by default

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-6.0

With the release of powershell 7, seems like it is time to move past ps 5.1 so I have installed in on a couple of servers to give it a go.

However I when I create a session to these servers from my pc with ps7 I am always running ps5.1 on the remote machine.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName name -ScriptBlock { 
        Write-Host $env:COMPUTERNAME
        $PSVersionTable.PsVersion
    }
```

Which outputs 5.1.17763.316.  Any ideas how to get the remote session to use version 7.0.0 preferably by default?

**Update**
making some progress with this, so though I would share.

On the remote machine in powershell 7 run the following command

```
Enable-PSRemoting
```

This will create some PsSessionConfigurations which you can see with the following command..

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration
```

Now you can do the following to create sessions from powershell 7

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -ScriptBlock { $PsVersionTable.PSVersion } -ConfigurationName Powershell.7
$session = New-PSSession ServerName -ConfigurationName Powershell.7
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { $PsVersionTable.PSVersion }
```

This now uses ps 7 on the remote session, happy days.  Now how to make this happen by default...?  From this [github issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11616) :

> set the default microsoft.powershell endpoint to any PowerShell they
>   choose

Which I think is what I want to do so switched back to ps 5.1 and tried this command:

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name microsoft.powershell | Set-PSSessionConfiguration -PSVersion 7.0
```

Only to get the following output:

> Set-PSSessionConfiguration : Cannot bind parameter 'PSVersion' to the
>   target. Exception setting "PSVersion": "The value 7.0 is not valid for
>   the PSVersion parameter. The available values are 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0,
>   5.1."

though I would try this in ps7 so switched back by running **pwsh** and ran the same command again to get he following...

> Write-Error: No session configuration matches criteria
>   "microsoft.powershell".

So still not quite sure how to make ps7 the default... :(

Comment: Thanks, mklement, seems strange that there is no way to set the default at a higher level than the session.  But at least the session level is a step better than the command level :D

Comment: Agreed, Alexis. Changing what endpoint PowerShell [Core] targets _by default_ is being considered, along with implementing more "sticky" configuration (policies): see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11616).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note:

- **It is the remoting *client* that determines what remoting endpoint (session configuration) to connect to** on the server machine - see below.
- Therefore, your own attempt,

> ```
> # WRONG
> Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name microsoft.powershell | 
>   Set-PSSessionConfiguration -PSVersion 7.0
> ```

is ineffective, because **[`Set-PSSessionConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-pssessionconfiguration) modifies *endpoint configurations* on the *server machine***, it doesn't control the *client*'s behavior.

Note that the **fundamental prerequisite** is that **PowerShell remoting must be *enabled*** on the server machine, which can be achieved either by opting to do so during installation via the MSI GUI installer, or by running [`Enable-PSRemoting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting) - with admin privileges - later.<sup>Tip of the hat to [Lars Fosdal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10002/lars-fosdal).</sup>

- Doing so from PowerShell (Core) creates the standard session configuration(s) named `PowerShell.<version>` that clients can opt to connect to - see below.
- To list all configurations defined on a server, run [`Get-PSSessionConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-pssessionconfiguration) with admin privileges.

---

**On a *client* machine**, you can **set a default** for what **session configuration *defined on the server* (remote machine) to connect to**, via the [**`$PSSessionConfigurationName`** preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#pssessionconfigurationname).

E.g., to target PowerShell 7 by default:

```
# When remoting, default to running PowerShell Core v7.x on the
# the target machines:
$PSSessionConfigurationName = 'PowerShell.7'
```

If you add the above to your `$PROFILE` file, future sessions will target PowerShell 7 by default.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238482/45375) for **more information**, which also shows **how to target a given server configuration in the context of individual commands**.

---

Note: Changing what endpoint PowerShell [Core] targets *by default* - which as of 7.2 is still *Window PowerShell* - is being considered: see [GitHub issue #11616](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11616).