# PowershellCore connection to a Powershell 5.1 remote computer?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.0, powershell-core

I want to know if it's possible to start from a Powershell 6/7 Host a Remote session on a host that only has Powershell 5.1 installed (that way I can access some Powershell 5.1 functions that can't be migrated to Powershell 6/7) ?

Regards,

Comment: You can have both instances of Posh installed, 5.1, and 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explicitly target a *Windows PowerShell* session (versions up to v5.1) on a remote computer, use
`-ConfigurationName Microsoft.Powershell` with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command), for instance.

In fact, as of PowerShell 7.1, this is still the *default* version that PowerShell remoting commands target, as reflected in [preference variable `$PSSessionConfigurationName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#pssessionconfigurationname).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58238481/45375) for more information.